# Filter logger from one appender but not another

Tags: java, logging, log4j, appender

I have two `appenders` in my logging configuration. One of them sends E-Mail on `ERROR` Events.

A class, that I have no control over, spams `ERROR` messages. So I still want to have that messages but not in both `appenders`.

This is about my file (reduced to the stuff relevant here, afaics):

```
<appender name="Logfile">...</appender>
<appender name="sendMailOnError">...</appender>

<logger name="spammingClass">
    <level value="info"/>
</logger>

<root>
   <level value="debug"/>
   <appender-ref ref="Logfile"/>
   <appender-ref ref="sendMailOnError"/>
</root>
```

So, my guess is that I can somehow exclude spammingClass in sendMailOnError but I don't know how.

Btw. I use Java, but I would like to not write an own Filter class for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by specifying appenders for `spammingClass` and setting additivity to `false`:

```
<logger name="spammingClass" additivity="false">
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Logfile"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use additivity, in your example change the spammingClass logger to :

```
<logger name="spammingClass" additivity="false">
    <level value="info"/>
</logger>
```

and it will do the trick.